# Почему не работает @import в css?

Tags: css

Файл test.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1251"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Text</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл style1.css

```css
@import (style2.css);
h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Файл style2.css

```css
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

В результате слово Text должно быть синим и фон страницы должен быть желтым, но фон не меняется. Правильно ли я подключил файл style2.css к файлу style1.css?

Comment: Я уверен, что у Вас неправильно реализован путь к style.css фалу

Comment: Все лежит в одной директории. И файлы имеют имена style1.css и style2.css

Comment: Проверьте мой ответ, который я привел ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте

```css
@import "style2.css";
h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Ответ взят с [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.asp)